# Java Servelet 3.0 File Upload to input stream - without intermediate folders or files being created

Tags: java, file-upload, stream, network-programming, java-io

I dont know how to do this, or whether is possible or wise, so any form of answer that points me to a library, example or reasoning will be helpful.

I need to upload and process some Java XML files (actually, XSLT files - XML Excel files).

I dont want to store the file on the server and then invoke processing on it. Instead, I want to stream the file in, and process it as a stream.

I also want to be able to process multipart file uploads, but still process that as an input stream.

I am expressly trying to avoid creating a file on disk for this.